# Portability issue in C

Tags: c, struct, portability, binaryfiles

I tried to make a program that writes **struct elements** to binary file and then writes the unique elements from the first file to another binary file. I compiled it with **gcc** and it works very good, but with **MinGW** the program freezes when it tries to open and create the second file. Do you have any idea where is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct element{
    char name[80];
    int p;
}ELEM;

void clear_stdin()
{
    char str[255];
    fgets(str,255,stdin);
}

int create()
{
    FILE *f;
    int d=0;
    int c;
    int n=0;
    ELEM s;
    f=fopen("file.bin","wb");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("create(): Could not open file.bin for read\n");
        return;
    }
    do{
    printf("Add elements to file?:\n1 - yes\n2 - no\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    if (c==1)
    {
        printf("Name=");
        clear_stdin();
        fgets(s.name,80,stdin);
        printf("P=");
        scanf("%d",&s.p);
        fwrite(&s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
        n++;
    }
    else
        d=1;
    } while(d==0);
    fclose(f);
    return n;
}

void show(int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    ELEM s;
    int i=0;
    if(n==0)
        return;
    f=fopen("file.bin","rb");
    while(i<n)
    {
        fread(&s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
        puts(s.name);
        printf("\t%d\n",s.p);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int add(int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    int d=0;
    int c;
    ELEM s;
    f=fopen("file.bin","ab");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("add(): Could not open file.bin for append\n");
        return;
    }
    do{
    printf("Add elements to file?:\n1 - yes\n2 - no\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    if (c==1)
    {
        printf("Name=");
        clear_stdin();
        fgets(s.name,80,stdin);
        printf("P=");
        scanf("%d",&s.p);
        fwrite(&s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
        n++;
    }
    else
        d=1;
    } while(d==0);
    fclose(f);
    return n;
}


void func(int n)
{
    FILE *f,*g;
    ELEM v[20],w;
    int i=0,j,k,x=0,s,gn=0,test;
    f=fopen("file.bin","rb");
    g=fopen("aux.bin","wb");
    if((g==NULL)||(f==NULL))
    {
        if(g==NULL)
            printf("function() : Could not open aux.bin for write\n");
        if(f==NULL)
            printf("function() : Could not open file.bin for read\n");
        return;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        fread(&v[i],sizeof(ELEM),1,f);

        i++;
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for(k=j+1;k<n;k++)
        {
            if(v[j].p==v[k].p)
                x=1;

        }
        if(x==0)
        {
            s=strcmp(v[j].name,v[k].name);
            if(s!=0)
            {
                fwrite(&v[j],sizeof(ELEM),1,g);
                fread(&w,sizeof(ELEM),1,g);

                gn++;
            }
        }
        x=0;
    }
    test=fclose(g);
    if(test!=0)
        printf("function() : failed to closed file g\n");
    test=fclose(f);
    if(test!=0)
        printf("function() : failed to closed file f\n");
    g=fopen("aux.bin","rb");
    if(g==NULL)
    {
        printf("function() : Could not open aux.bin for read\n");
        return;
    }
    if(gn==0)
        return;
    i=0;
    while(i<gn)
    {
        fread(&w,sizeof(ELEM),1,g);
        puts(w.name);
        printf("\t%d\n",w.p);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(g);
}

int main()
{
    int k=0,r,n;
    do{
        printf("1 - create file\n2 - add elements to file\n3 - show elements\n4 - put unique elements in another file\n5 - exit program\n");
        scanf("%d",&r);
        switch(r)
        {
            case 1 : n=create(); break;
            case 2 : n=add(n); break;
            case 3 : show(n); break;
            case 4 : func(n); break;
            case 5 : k=1; break;
            default : printf("Command unrecognized!\n");
        }
    } while(k==0);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
function **func()** is the only problem.

EDIT: Yes I can run it under gdb.

EDIT:
sizeof(ELEM)=84 offsetof(ELEM,p)=80 in both cases.

Comment: Can you shorten the code a bit? That's a lot to ask someone to read.

Comment: You need to produce a simple example, preferably non-interactive, demonstrating the problem.  Chances are, you will figure out what is going on before you have an example worth posting here.

Comment: How come struct-serialization questions seem to pop up once every half-hour today?

Comment: on which like does the program freeze? could you run it under gdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow guys you will not guess this:  `aux.bin`, actually anything `aux.*` is a reserved filename on Windows! That's why it is taking forever! Take a look here so you dont accidentally choose another reserved filename:
[windows file name specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (search the page for 'aux')

Comment: This is also true for CON, LPT1, etc.  Found this out the hard way in a production system a few years back.